# xlwt: Numbers stored as string have decimal point in Excel

Tags: python-3.x, xlwt

I am currently using xlrd and xlwt in order to scan through tables and store the found information in a different excel file.
The input file has some integers that I want to use as a primary key and I store them as a string:

`sheet.write(row, column, str(value))`

However when I open the output excel file, I see these keys as following:

```
220
230
240.0
250.0
```

I want to get rid of the random decimal point and have an uniform format for the strings/integers.
I could format them in excel, but I get a bunch of output files and need a way to make this in an automated manner.

Answer (score 0):

```
    sheet.write(row, column, str(value),easyxf(num_format_str='0'))
```